# How do I send an automatic email from Windows Phone 8.1 universal app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Good morning,

is it possible to send an automatic email message within a Windows Phone 8.1 universal app? I want to set an eMail adress and then the message will be send from this address.

Is it possible without interaction of the user?

Answer (score 0):

I think anything in the Windows Phone SDK will enforce user interaction.
It is possible nevertheless.  I have some experience of MailMessage component, which lets you achieve what you desire - but I'm sure there's others out there too.

http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage

Comment: I've tried this component, but it doesn't work within a univeral app, because the System.Windows.dll is missing. Do you know another component?

Comment: I've had a look through notes on a related project of mine, and I was unable to find anything else suitable at the time. (This was some months ago though).  Since MailMessage vendor's forum seems to be down, they might be able to offer support via direct email?..  Sorry I couldnt be of more help :S

Answer (score 0):

By design, this is not possible: sending email from a user's email address without their knowledge is a security risk.

An alternative is to build a webservice that sends the email, and have your application call that webservice, instead.